# Photo don't uploaded correctly GCS App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on my upload.java servlet to store .jpg to GCS.

I use GCS client library instead of Google Cloud Storage API. But I dont't find any sample to upload photo (doPost Method) so my code doesn't work...

Sending is a success (I can see my photo on GCS with a good size 465.24KB), but when I try to view this one, i can't:

[image]

Here is my code:

**upload.java servlet**
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws IOException {

```
            //Read the file contents from the input stream
            GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();

            GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, FILENAME);


            GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
                .mimeType("image/jpeg")
                .acl("public-read")
                .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value")
                .build();

            GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);
            InputStream is = request.getInputStream();

            try {
                copy(is, Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel));
            } finally {
                writeChannel.close();
                is.close();
            }          

        }

      private void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
            while (bytesRead != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
            }
        }
```

**android code (To send photo)**

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("adress.appengine.com/upload");        


                //On créé un fichier File qui contient la photo que l'on vient de prendre (Accessible via son Path) 
                File f = new File(AccueilActivity.fileUri.getPath());       

                //On créé un FileBody (Contenu de notre requête http POST) contenant notre photo
                FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(f);

                //Permet de créer une requête avec plusieurs partie
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

                //On ajoute notre photo avec le mot clé file.
                reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);

                //On set notre requête HTTP
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

                //On execute notre requete HTTP Post, et on appele du coup automatiquement le servlet "uploaded",
                //et on met la réponse dans response.
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);                   

                //Ici on récupère l'entête de notre réponse HTTP (Tout sauf le code réponse)
                HttpEntity urlEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found (And by myself) the solution to my problem! And I pretty proud of that =D

**The code for Android:**

```
//Actions à réaliser en fond
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //Création d'une requête HTTP
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  

            //On construit notre adresse Post grâce à ce que l'on vient de récupérer
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://your_id.appspot.com/upload");

            //On créé un fichier File qui contient la photo que l'on vient de prendre (Accessible via son Path) 
            File f = new File(AccueilActivity.fileUri.getPath());

            //Et là on essaie !
            try {               

                 MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                 entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE); 
                 entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("Photo_a_uploader", f);             
                 entityBuilder.addTextBody("Type", "Type que l'utilisateur a choisi");

                 httppost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());
                 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);              


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // Si on tombe dans le catch, on set notre variable à 2.        
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Si on tombe dans le catch, on set notre variable à 2.            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**The code App Engine**

```
 @Override
          public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
              throws ServletException, IOException {

            //Read the file contents from the input stream
            GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();

            GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, FILENAME);          

            GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
                    .mimeType("image/jpg")
                    .acl("public-read")
                    .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value")
                    .build();

            GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);

            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();

            res.setContentType("text/plain");             

            try {
                FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);

                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
                        InputStream stream = item.openStream();

                        if (item.isFormField()) {
                          log.warning("Champs texte avec id: " + item.getFieldName()+", et nom: "+Streams.asString(stream));
                        } else {
                          log.warning("Nous avons un fichier à uploader : " + item.getFieldName() +
                                      ", appelé = " + item.getName());

                          // You now have the filename (item.getName() and the
                          // contents (which you can read from stream). Here we just
                          // print them back out to the servlet output stream, but you
                          // will probably want to do something more interesting (for
                          // example, wrap them in a Blob and commit them to the
                          // datastore).
                          // Open a channel to write to it


                          byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(stream);

                          try {
                                writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
                          } finally {
                                writeChannel.close();
                                stream.close();
                          }        
                        }        
                  }
                } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



         }
```

I hope these sample help you with app engine and google cloud storage !

Comment: FYI - I included these imports to enable your solution: `import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams; import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload; import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator; import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream; import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;`