# Can I use Android classes on Google App Engine?

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Question is simple, on the Google App Engine (whether Java servlet or Endpoints or whatever), can I use Android classes? i.e. Can I use something like `Bitmap` or any other classes in the `android.graphics` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you import the SDK android on your project, but I don't recommend you to do that.

If you want to manipulate image in App Engine, you can use this Image Java API: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

If you want to upload image in Servlet App Engine, here is a good example: [Photo don't uploaded correctly GCS App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778367/photo-dont-uploaded-correctly-gcs-app-engine)

Hope I help you

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use `android.graphics.*` Please check the [The JRE Class White List](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) for more details. The class list is too long to paste it here.